# mouseup event on document.documentElement does not fire with alert

Tags: javascript, html

I need to detect `mouseup` event after `mousedown` on the document.

I have tried to add an event listener to `document` and `document.documentElement` with no success.

I need possibly a cross platform solution without jquery.
Notes: problem appears on not all browsers using `alert()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/0f7vrzh7/8/

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
alert('mousedown');
});

document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
alert('mouseup')
});
```

Comment: Try it on body element

Comment: try console.log instead of alert, it's working fine!!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In certain browsers the first alert would stop the second event. It works even with `alert` in IE11 for example. In the browsers where you experience this issue the alert box blocks the UI before the `mouseup` event is processed or propagated to the element you have the event handler attached to. Change to `console.log()` statements in your event handlers and the events are fired as you expect them to. [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/0f7vrzh7/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer....Do you have an idea why the second alert is being stopped on certain browsers?

Comment: Console.logs are always better than alerts. They don't stop the UI, and don't hurt if you forget to remove them.

Answer (score 5):

it's yours alert block the mouseup event. try with

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0";
});

document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    alert('mouseup')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0f7vrzh7/16/